# C++: fopen/fgets stops at random point in reading XML file

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to read an XML file (29.3 MB in size) and print out the contents to the console using a small C++ program. The problem is that it stops quite early on in the file (not even 1%) and I can't figure out why. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
const char * fn = "countries.xml";          // file name
const static int maxString = 1024;  // read buffer size

// read the file
printf("reading file\n");
char buf[maxString];
FILE * fr = fopen(fn, "r");

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    fgets(buf, maxString, fr);
    printf(buf);
}
fclose(fr);
printf("done.\n");

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** This for loop was actually used to see if something went wrong with my loop conditioning before. Where my loop was in fact:

```
char * rc;
while(( rc = fgets(buf, maxString, fr) )) {
    printf(buf);
}
```

However, no matter which form of loop I use and which condition (I can make i as high as I want), it stops printing to the console at the same point in the XML file.

Comment: In your for loop, why are you iterating to 20000? You should keep iterating until you've read the whole file.

Comment: Why the magic number of `20000` in your loop?

Comment: Well, `20000 * 1024` is about 20 megs. Not enough to read the whole file, but it should get a lot farther than 1%..

Comment: And what if some of the lines are 10 characters, 4 characters, 20 characters, etc. and not 1,024 characters?  All you did was read 20,000 lines, not 20,000 * 1024 characters.  And how do you know what percentage has been read?

Comment: Oh right, `fgets` stops at newline. My bad. Yeah, than that probably is the issue. Someone should probably put that in an answer rather than a comment, so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: You really should be reading until EOF, not 20000.

Comment: Sorry, I explained the 20,000 lines in an edit to my question. The 1% is an educated guess based on my knowledge of the line the text stops at compared to the entire document. I was talking about how much gets printed to console, not making a general statement about the reading of the document itself.

Comment: Try using freopen(fn,"r",stdin) to open file and  string s; cin>>s; to read.

Comment: @Omnia87 Is the portion you get in the console from the starting of your file or from last of your file?

Comment: Redirect your output to a new file and compare that to the original. It may just be a limitation of your terminal console.

Comment: Is this running on Windows?  Perhaps there's a Ctrl-Z in the XML file for some reason?  Try `FILE * fr = fopen(fn, "rb")`

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm running it on Kubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @Omnia87 Did you copy the file from a Windows system?  If so, text based files in Windows are **not** the same as text based files in Unix / Linux.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas read with `fgets` until `NULL` not `EOF`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did indeed copy the file from a Windows system. The 'rb' argument however doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: that ought not be a problem. Even if the local version of `fgets` does *not* treat `\r` and `\n` the same, the 'other' character will be read as any other character. In particular, it would not explain why it works for a certain number of lines and then suddenly stop.

Comment: @WeatherVane: no, you read until EOF. NULL can also indicate error. To distinguish, you use `ferror()` or `feof()`.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas please read the man page for `fgets`. *"NULL is returned to indicate an error or an end-of-file condition."* The idiom is `while(fgets(buf, maxString, fr) != NULL) {...}`

Comment: @WeatherVane: I did read the man page. What I said is 100% correct. You call `feof()`: if true, you're done. If you _also_ want to check for error, you can _also_ call `ferror()`. If you do call both, then the return value of `fgets()` is irrelevant. IMHO, it makes for clearer code to be explicit about it rather than having to remember what NULL means.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas have it your own way, but I never have trouble remembering what `NULL` means. Your way seems overly complicated. Your original comment was *"You really should be reading until EOF"* and I retorted because `EOF` is not returned by `fgets`. That's the way you do it with `fgetc`, idiomatically `while((ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {...}`

Comment: @WeatherVane: I _never said_ `fgets()` _returned_ EOF. I said "read until EOF" meaning the "end of file condition." I _never said_ the literal `EOF`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code easily leads to undefined behavior should `buf` contain a `'%'`.

`printf()` treats its first augment as a format and may expect following matching arguments to go with `"%s"` , etc.  Of course an ill-formed specifier like `"%S"` leads to undefined behavior.

```
// bad
while (fgets(buf, maxString, fr)) {
  printf(buf);
```

Use `fputs()`.

```
// good
while (fgets(buf, maxString, fr)) {
  fputs(buf, stdout);
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

For `gcc` at a minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

I also use:

```
-Wconversion -std=c99
```

the output from the compiler shows several problems (all warnings) in the code.   In general, warnings should never be ignored.

1. unused parameter: `argc`
2. unused parameter: `argv[]`
3. call to printf() with no format string literal and no format specifiers
4. 'static' not at beginning of declaration.

Then the looping method leaves a lot to be desired,

1. fixed number of loops
2. fails to check returned value from function: `fgets()`

Then, in C, creating a static const variable takes up room in the file memory space.  Much better to #define that value

for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, consistently indent the code.

1. indent after every opening brace `{`
2. un-indent before every closing brace `}`

When indenting, never use tabs as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Suggest using 4 spaces for each level of indent as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows room for many indent levels across the page.

When calling many/most of the system functions, the returned value needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_STRING (1024)

int main( void )
{
    const char * fn = "countries.xml";          // file name

    // read the file
    printf("reading file\n");
    char buf[ MAX_STRING ];

    FILE * fr = NULL;
    if( NULL == ( fr = fopen(fn, "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for read of countries.xml failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, fr ) )
    {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    fclose(fr);
    printf("done.\n");

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```